# Software Developer

Tags: application-development

i am a software developer and want to try out ubuntu. 
My question is: which distribution of ubuntu do you prefer, 
if you want to write source code in C++/OpenGL or Java/Javascipt ?

Thanks to your answer, and greetings from germany.

Comment: many in the Ubuntu community hates Java, I don't know why but many do. Not sure if it's relevant...

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way. You should be asking yourself first which tools you are planning on using and then researching to see if they are available on the platform you are planning to use. Having said that, most mainstream tools are available in Ubuntu out of the box or can be used with minimal configuration. And as for flavors, well, I like chocolate, others prefer vanilla :-)

Comment: Defetively related http://askubuntu.com/q/360161

Answer (score 1):

Which flavour of ubuntu do you prefer? Oh, this is going to go down as a recurring topic! Any Ubuntu-based ditro or any distro, is good enough to do your job. Now it's all upon taste. Their base is the same. I use Ubuntu, BTW!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any Ubuntu distribution it's more or less just a question of which desktop environment you like. Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu. Have a look at the different distros.

I don't think there is any Ubuntu distribution which does the job of writing C++ or Java better than any other - it's just down to a matter of taste which kind of work flow and looks of your OS you prefer.

I personally use Ubuntu with Unity, even after being around in the lands of Xubuntu and Cinnamon recently.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which *flavor* of Ubuntu you use. All Ubuntu distributions come with support for most of the commonly used developing software (MYSQL, NetBeans, IDEs for most languages etc.).

Choose whichever flavor you like best based on Visuals, System Requirements, interface etc.